# Using request in python for CURL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, curl, python-requests

When I use CURL, I am getting the below output, which says that proxy was able to connect to the endpoint via proxy. CURL output was 200 connection established and later showing the 401 Unauthorized. I am OK as long as proxy was able to connect (200 connection established) but when I execute the python code, the python output is showing only 301. I only care about if the connection can be made over the proxy or not. Can I please how can I check the (200 connection established) like in the CURL output using the python?

```
export HTTPS_PROXY=<proxy_details> && curl -vvv https://www.sap.com


* About to connect() to proxy proxy.abc.local.port 1256 (#0)
*   Trying 169.31.123.234...
* Connected to proxy.abc.local.port () port 1256 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.sap.com:443
> CONNECT www.sap.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.sap.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=www.sap.com,O=SAP SE,L=Walldorf,ST=Baden-Württemberg,C=DE
*   start date: May 26 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*   expire date: May 31 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*   common name: www.sap.com
*   issuer: CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: www.sap.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 238
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
< Location: https://www.sap.com/index.html
< Date: Sat, 24 Jul 2021 03:44:35 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.sap.com/index.html">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host   proxy.abc.local.port left intact
```

python code

```
import requests 
proxies = { 'https':'proxy.config.pcp.local:3128'}
res = requests.get('https://www.sap.com', proxies=proxies)
print (res.status_code)
```

output:

```
301
```

Comment: Both (the cURL call and the Python code) are returning a 301. And if there would be a proxy issue an exception would be raised. I don't understand where your problem is.

Comment: In the curl output,   it shows  "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established" after that it shows "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently". as long as it shows "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established" i am fine. but when using the request module it shows only 301.

Comment: Have you considered that the `requests` library just does not show the `200`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably try to directly send only the CONNECT request then, to have a chance at looking at thats response code.

But I don't think Python `requests` allows that. Lower-level tools like `http.client` do though:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("proxy.config.pcp.local", 1256)
conn.request("CONNECT", "www.sap.com:443",'',{"Host":"www.sap.com:443"})
response = conn.getresponse()
print(response.status)
```

(use `http.client.HTTPSConnection` in case of an HTTPS proxy)

Comment: One of the issue i noticed with http.client is that is can't pass the URL's like a1231232.slack.com/archive/CH234424P. it always give 503 error with http.client  but when i tried the CURL i can see the HTTP 200.

Comment: This is expected, you need to purge your input. You should also see in CURL:

* Connected .. (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to a1231232.slack.com:443
> CONNECT a1231232.slack.com:443 HTTP/1.1

Also no Path here. This is expected, CONNECT just asks the proxy for a TCP tunnel, so host+port is enough. Path is only sent once that tunnel is established.

Answer (score 0):

The connection is not made over proxy too. It shows `200 Connection established` at first because the socket connection is established but then it hits the redirect and it throws `301 Moved Permanently`. When you are using python's request module it only shows the final status code (which is 301) and not the intermediate socket connections.